# How to improve the design pattern of this Screen Window system?

Tags: design, design-patterns, c++

I have a Screen Window system, a Screen (IScreen as interface), which holds a window, either WindowA or WindowB. System can switch window by calling stateChanged:

```
class IScreen{
public:
    virtual void stateChanged(int state)=0;
};

class Window{};

class WindowA : public Window{
public:
    WindowA(IScreen* screen){
        screen->stateChanged(1);
    }
};

class WindowB : public Window{
public:
    WindowB(IScreen* screen){}
};

class Screen : public IScreen{
protected:
    Window* window;
public:
    Screen(){this->window=NULL;}
    void stateChanged(int state){
        if(window!=NULL){
            delete window;
        }
        switch(state){
            case 0:
            window=new WindowA(this);
            printf("state 0 with WindowA\n");
            break;
            case 1:
            window=new WindowB(this);
            printf("state 1 with WindowB\n");
            break;
        }
    }
};

int main(){
    Screen screen;
    screen.stateChanged(0);
    return 0;
}
```

but I don't know if this design pattern is correct, first, for each window, call "statechanged()" may potentially destroy itself, second, if it switches window at the same call stack,i.e.:call "statechanged()" inside another window, the window that attached to screen at last is not the same as the window that call "statechanged()" at last, see the output when I create WindowA and then create WindowB:

```
state 1 with WindowB
state 0 with WindowA
```

Is there any design pattern to improve the system if the current pattern has some problems?

Comment: What does it matter if it is "correct" or not? Does it work like you intend it to? Are you having a problem with it now?

Comment: So the thing about design patterns is that they need backing use cases. Can you tell us more about the problems you're trying to solve in your final solution and how this is not working? For example, two different types of solutions come to mind with your code. The first is more of a full window event handling stack. For that, look at how WndProc in Windows does things. The second is something much more indirect, like the use of hyperlinked "windows", see Hypercard or WWW designs for that. But the reality is that what you're doing may be fine without a larger architecture - help us understand!